# Minimum value of $a>0$ for which $x^a \ge \log_e(x)$ for all $x>0$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Find the minimum value of $a>0$ for which $x^a \ge \log_e(x)$ for all $x>0$ .

---

I tried to plot graphs and saw that $x^{1/e}$ is above $\log_e(x)$ but $^{1/3}$ goes below $\log_e(x)$. I can't figure out if $a$ can be less than $\frac{1}{e}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would like to find the minimum value of $a$ such that $f(x):=x^a-\ln x\geq 0$(where $\ln x= \log_e x$). We find the minimum value of $f(x)$. We have $$f'(x)=ax^{a-1}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{ax^a-1}{x}$$
and $f'(k)=0$ where $k^a=\frac{1}{a}$. $f'(x)$ changes sign from negative to positive near $x=k$, and it changes sign no where other, so $f(x)$ achieves minimum in only one point, $x=k$. We have $\ln k =-\frac{\ln a}{a} $, so the minimum value of $f(x)$ is $f(k)=k^a-\ln k=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{\ln a}{a}=\frac{\ln a +1}{a}$. We want the minimum value to be larger than or equal to zero, so $\ln a+1\geq 0$, $a\geq \frac{1}{e}$. This concludes that the minimum value is in fact $a=\frac{1}{e}$, and no smaller value than $\frac{1}{e}$ could achieve the same property.

Answer (score 0):

Without using derivative .

---

Let $\thinspace x=e^t$, then we have :

$$
\begin{align}&x^a≥\ln x,\thinspace \forall x>0\\
\iff &e^{at}≥t,\thinspace t\in \mathbb R\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

If $\thinspace t≤0$, then $e^{at}≥t$ always holds. Therefore, we will work over $t\in\mathbb R^{+}\thinspace .$

Assuming that $\thinspace a<\frac 1e$, then it sufficies to show that, $e^{at}<t$ has a solution .

Indeed, if $\thinspace a=\frac{1}{N}$ and $N>e$ then we see that, $e^{at}<t$  holds for $t=N\thinspace .$ Therefore, $\thinspace a≥\frac 1e\thinspace .$

If $\thinspace a=\frac 1e$, then using the well-known inequality $e^x≥x+1$, we have :

$$
\begin{align}&e^{\frac te}≥t=e^{\ln t}\\
\iff &\frac te ≥ \ln t\\
\iff &e^{\ln t-1}≥\left(\ln t-1\right)+1\end{align}
$$

This implies that $\thinspace x^{\frac 1e}≥\ln x$ holds $\forall x>0$, which means $a=\frac 1e$ is minimum .

Comment: @lonestudent I was actually considering only positive $a$. Sorry for that ambiguity in the question. No need to consider $a<0$.

Comment: When you put $x=e^t$ and $x>0$ then it does not necessarily imply $t>0$ but $t$ could be any real number.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh If you still see *technical* errors, I will ask you to please note me . Thank you for your reviewing .